# EditText Insertion Point same color as text (@null not working)

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I want to make the EditText Cursor color same as text but:

```
android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
```

isn't working.

I changed it using the primeryAccent color in the themes(style) but would prefer if it just takes the color of text(so I wouldn't make many styles for each editText). Am I missing something?

The editText:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/search_value"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/transparent"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:hint="Search People..."
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/arrow_search_indicator"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/search_container"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@id/search_container"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/search_container"
    android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textColorHint="@color/search_hint_blue"
    android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"/>
```

Edited here:

Image:

[image]

That pink thing(Sorry if i misnamed it)

Comment: Setting the android:textCursorDrawable attribute to @null should result in the use of android:textColor as the cursor color.

Attribute "textCursorDrawable" is available in API level 12 and higher

Comment: When you set `android:textCursorDrawable="@null"` , the color of Cursor should be the color of `android:textColor` so make sure you set the `android:textColor` explicitly in xml file

Comment: The color is staying pink if the coloraccent is set to pink after i addandroid:textCursorDrawable="@null"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edittext cursor color you want changes your color.

```
<EditText  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/color_cursor"
    />
```

Then create drawalble xml: `color_cursor`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <size android:width="3dp" />
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"  />
</shape>
```